# Does React build/index.html change every time you bundle?

Tags: reactjs

So every time I run `npm run build`, does the `index.html` file in the `build/` directory change? I just see this huge glob of minified JS. This is assuming I don't change the index.html file in the default public/src folder (can't remember).

Also, is the same true for Vue and other SPAs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have files hash turned on for built JS files, than `index.html` will change all the time according to those hash values, i.e. `main.91a301df.js` and other files that you produce with `build` task. (This is by default turned on in Create react app)

You can see more about hashing all files here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/#output-filenames

This is Webpack default configuration if you are using Create react app.

As for Vue.js, I am not sure, but most of the build tasks in off the shelf cli have that hashing option enabled. Angular has it also.

Comment: Ah that's right. I forgot about those links and scripts. Thanks! Will accept in a couple minutes.

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help. Cheers